# What does the letter "E" mean in the Ecore?

Tags: eclipse, modeling, eclipse-emf-ecore

Is it maybe EMF or EMOF? Eclipse? Or something totally different or nothing at all...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: EMF logo]
From the [EMF page](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/?project=emf):

> EMF - The core EMF framework includes a **[meta model (Ecore)](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc?org/eclipse/emf/ecore/package-summary.html#details)** for describing models and runtime support for the models including:
>
> - change notification,
> - persistence support with default XMI serialization,
> - and a very efficient reflective API for manipulating EMF objects generically.

So I guess Ecore stands for "EMF core metamodel" here.

---

From this [Eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.emf.doc/references/overview/EMF.html):

> For those of you that are familiar with OMG (Object Management Group) MOF (Meta Object Facility), you may be wondering how EMF relates to it.
>   Actually, EMF started out as an implementation of the MOF specification but evolved from there based on the experience we gained from implementing a large set of tools using it.
>   EMF can be thought of as a highly efficient Java implementation of a core subset of the MOF API.
>   **However, to avoid any confusion, the MOF-like core meta model in EMF is called Ecore.**
>
> In the current proposal for MOF 2.0, a similar subset of the MOF model, which it calls **EMOF (Essential MOF)**, is separated out. There are small, mostly naming differences between Ecore and EMOF; however, EMF can transparently read and write serializations of EMOF.

So the "Essential" for "E" does have some ground here.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but not exact, there is no evidence. It matters, because when reading about EMF, you will discover that it started as an MOF implementation, so it may be that it really was 'Essential core' and then from that EMOF evolved. This is another theory, but there is no proof for either.

Comment: @Gabrel: true, I have updated my answer to reflect that origin.

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I ment, however it still is only sort of a hint not an answer, so I won't accept till definite answer, but your answer deserved upvote